# pop record from ActiveRecord without deleting in database Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

In rails 3.2 `pop` helps in removing the record from ActiveRecord.

```
rec = User.find(1).histories
rec.pop => remove last history and output class will be in ActiveRecord
```

In Rails 5.2, same pop is not working.

Looking for same ActiveRecord class as output.

Also, the record should not be removed in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
rec = User.find(1).histories.to_a.pop
```

Comment: But required output should be in ActiveRecord class not array

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.